# Faithfully flat descent of projectivity for non-commutative rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, noncommutative-rings

I am looking for a reference for the following statement (or another one explained further below):

Let $M$ be a module over a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ and $R'\supset R$ a faithfully flat ring extension. If $M\otimes_R R'$ is projective as an $R'$-module, then so is $M$ as an $R$-module.

Perry has produced [a very detailed write-up](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0038v1.pdf) of the commutative case. The non-commutative case should follow from the characterization of projective modules as those which are flat Mittag-Leffler modules and split as a direct sum of countably generated modules. This characterization, even for the non-commutative case, is attributed to Raynaud-Gruson's [*Critères de platitude et de projectivité Techniques de 'platification' d'un module*](https://eudml.org/doc/142084) for example by Drinfeld in [*Infinite-dimensional vector bundles in algebraic geometry*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309155.pdf) (Theorem 2.2). But the RG paper starts with the words "Soient A un anneau commutatif..." and my French is not good enough to verify that this assumption is not needed later on. Furthermore, Perry states in his paper that the original proof by Raynaud-Gruson had a gap which requires fixing even in the commutative case.

A reference for any of these two statements making it very clear that non-commutative rings are also considered would thus be very helpful.

Comment: What is an algebra over a non-commutative ring? The problem is that, if $k$ is a commutative ring, then an algebraic object $R$ in the category of $k$-modules is just a ring map $k\to R$. This does not seem to be correct in the non-commutative case. The first question would be, in place of $k$-modules, we take left modules, right modules or bimodules?

Comment: @Yai0Phah In order to be compatible with the phrasing of the question above, one would consider right modules throughout.